# I don't know how to change the status of a modal

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Good morning, I am in a React and JS project and I am still learning React and some things are difficult to do and I have a small problem with which I can't make any progress.

I had a modal with one color for all the results, but I have been told that depending on the result it is necessary to show one color or another. I have it defined this way in the Modal component:

```
const headerModal = {
    0: "modal-error", //red
    1: "modal-ok",    //green
  };
```

And in another component I have what would go inside the kata, everything that has the className "statusKata" should come out with headerModal={1} and the "Not started" with headerModal={0} but I don't know how to implement it, that code is this below:

```
import React from 'react';

const DetailUserKata = (props) => {
  return (
    <>
    {!props.statusKata ? 
      <div>Obteniendo datos...</div> : 
      props.statusKata.length ? 
        <div>
          <div className="statusKata"><label>Autor: </label> {props.statusKata[0].author_login_txt}</div>
          <div className="statusKata"><label>Cuenta de GitHub: </label> {props.statusKata[0].autor_github_url}</div>
        </div> :
        <div>Not started</div>
    }
    </>
  );
}

export default DetailUserKata;
```

At first, in the page where the modal is shown I had it as below with the header={1} with the green color (modal-ok), but I have to change it:

```
<Modal show={showKata} handleClose={hideModalKata} header={1} title="Detalles de la kata">
        {<DetailUserKata statusKata={detail} />}
</Modal >
```

Thanks in advance! And any feedback for change or help is always welcome.

Comment: You want to show modal with different header color depending on status, am I right?

Comment: Yes! In modal-error (0) the modal header would be red, and in modal-ok (1) it would be green. At the moment the modal is in green color because in the third block of code that I show I have it indicated this way but I want to change it. 

Sorry for my bad English, I try to explain it well

Answer (score 0):

Replace `green` and `red` with your desired colors

```js
import React from 'react';

const DetailUserKata = (props) => {
  return (
    <div style={{background-color: props.header === headerModal[1] ? 'green' : 
                                     props.header === headerModal[0] ? 'red' :''}
    }>
    {!props.statusKata ? 
      <div>Obteniendo datos...</div> : 
      props.statusKata.length ? 
        <div>
          <div className="statusKata"><label>Autor: </label> {props.statusKata[0].author_login_txt}</div>
          <div className="statusKata"><label>Cuenta de GitHub: </label> {props.statusKata[0].autor_github_url}</div>
        </div> :
        <div>Not started</div>
    }
    <div/>
  );
}

export default DetailUserKata;
```

and move `header` prop to `DetailUserKata`

```js
<Modal show={showKata} handleClose={hideModalKata} title="Detalles de la kata">
        {<DetailUserKata statusKata={detail} header={headerModal[1]}  />}
</Modal >
```